# Repetitive array value being pushed into the new array

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
var videoIndex = 0;
function createVideoList() {
  var list = "";
  var v = 0;
  $.each(videoarr, function (index, value) {
    var name = videoarr[v].name;
    var img = videoarr[v].img;
    list = list + "<div id='video'><a href='#'><img src='" + img + "' id='videoimg'/><h4>" + name + 
 "</h4></a></div>"
    v = v + 1;
  });
  $('#videoresult').html(list);
}

  $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#videopage", function () {
  createVideoList();

  displayLikedVideo();
})



function displayLikedVideo() {
  var liked = "";
  var i = 0;
  $.each(filed_video, function (index, value) {
    var name = filed_video[i].name;
    var img = filed_video[i].img;
    liked = liked + "<div id='video'><a href='#'><img src='" + img + "' id='videoimg'/><h4>" + name 
   + "</h4></a></div>"
    i = i + 1;
  });
  $('#liked_video').html(liked);
}
```

The first time I tapped the saved button it pushed the array value one time into the new array. However, if I try to save the other array value. it will push two times into the new array:

[image]

So far and so on if I try to save the 3rd array value, it pushes 3 times to the new array. Sorry for the bad explanation... Anyone knows the reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to push values one by one in the array? Means on the first tap, insert the first item, the second tap insert the second item? If so, you haven't incremented your `videoIndex` hence it is pushing the first item only. In this case, you need to increment your `videoIndex`:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#videopage', function () {
  $('#saved_video').on('tap', function () {
    filed_video.push(videoarr[videoIndex]);
    console.log(filed_video);
    videoIndex=videoIndex+1;
  });
})
```

If you want to reset the array every time and insert fresh item, the issue is with your global declaration `var filed_video = [];`. Remove this from top and include inside your action like this.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#videopage', function () {
  $('#saved_video').on('tap', function () {
    var filed_video = [];
    filed_video.push(videoarr[videoIndex]);
    console.log(filed_video);
  });
})
```

**EDIT**

```js
var filed_video = [];
var videoarr = [{
  name: 'Japchae: 잡채 (Glass noodles stir-fried with vegetables)',
  date: '4 Nov 2014',
  img: 'https://www.maangchi.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/07/japchae_plate.jpg',
  YoutubeId: 'i1djfV9uigc',
  FullRecipeUrl: 'https://www.maangchi.com/recipe/japchae',
  description: 'Japchae, sweet potato starch noodles stir fried with vegetables and meat, is one of Korea’s best-loved dishes, and one of the most popular on my website as well.Stir frying each ingredient separately seems like a lot of labor, but each one requires a different cooking time and a bit of care, and keeping the color and freshness of each ingredient intact makes for a stunning final presentation.'
},
{
  name: 'Hot and spicy rice cake',
  date: '30 Jan 2013',
  img: 'https://www.maangchi.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/ddeokbokki_sizzlingpot.jpg',
  YoutubeId: 'TA3Uo3a9674',
  FullRecipeUrl: 'https://www.maangchi.com/recipe/tteokbokki',
  description: 'When I lived in Korea I learned the secret to making good tteokbokki from a famous place in a market. It was run by an old lady who could always be found stirring her tteokbokki. People were lined up to buy it.'
}
];

var videoIndex = 0;
function createVideoList() {
  var list = "";
  var v = 0;
  $.each(videoarr, function (index, value) {
    var name = videoarr[v].name;
    var img = videoarr[v].img;
    list = list + "<div id='video'><a href='#'><img src='" + img + "' id='videoimg'/><h4>" + name + 
 "</h4></a></div>"
    v = v + 1;
  });
  $('#videoresult').html(list);
}
function displayLikedVideo() {
  var liked = "";
  var i = 0;
  $.each(filed_video, function (index, value) {
    var name = filed_video[i].name;
    var img = filed_video[i].img;
    liked = liked + "<div id='video'><a href='#'><img src='" + img + "' id='videoimg'/><h4>" + name 
   + "</h4></a></div>"
    i = i + 1;
  });
  $('#liked_video').html(liked);
}
$(function(){
$('#saved_video').on('click', function () {
    filed_video.push(videoarr[videoIndex]);
    console.log(filed_video);
    videoIndex=videoIndex+1;
  });
  createVideoList();

  displayLikedVideo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="page" id="videopage">
     <div data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" id="videoheader">
     <h2 id="recipeHeader">Recipe Video</h2>
      <p>Upload Video</p>
     <a href="#mypanel" id="myLiked">Liked</a>

     <div class="wrap no">
       <div class="search">
         <input type="search" name="search" class="searchTerm" data- 
            role="none" placeholder="Recipe video name">
         <button class="searchButton" data-role="none">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
         </button>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" data-filter="true" data- 
     input="#filterTable-input" class="ui-responsive">
      <ul data-role="listview" id="videoresult">
      </ul>
      <div data-role="panel" id='mypanel' data-position="right" data- 
      display="overlay">
        <h4>The Favourite Recipe</h4>
        <ul data-role="listview" id="liked_video">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
    <!-- end of videopage -->

   <!-- start of videodetailpage -->
  <div data-role="page" id="videodetailpage">
    <div data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
      <a href="#" data-rel='back' data-role="none" id="back"><i class="fa 
      fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <a id="saved_video">Like This 
      </a>
   </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
     <div id='youtubeVideo'></div>
     <h4 id='name'></h4>
     <p id="date"></p>
     <div id='desc'></div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry i have updated my html page, what i want is every time i tapped on the saved_video button..The particular value i have tapped will be pushed into the new array...and i have tried both methods u suggest...but the repetitive kind of still there.. do u have other suggestions? Thank you so much for helping

Comment: if i try to tap on the second value to push it into array it kind of pushes the particular value 2 times into the array. if i tapped on another value then it will push that particular value for 3 times into array

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?  I am a bit confused.

Comment: I have doubts. I can see only one `saved_video` button. It is not in the loop. How are you getting multiple like buttons?

Comment: the createvideolist function will display all the array value in the videodetail page html..So every time that particular page 's save button is pressed, i want to push that value to the array only

Comment: Can you please elaborate "page 's save"? What do you mean by this?

Comment: It means the save button in that particular page is pressed..then i want to push the value that is displayed in that particular page in to the new array

Comment: I added the fiddle and updated events from `tap` to `click` to run it in the fiddle. Now can you check the fiddle and let me know what is wrong? Here, `Like This` is nothing but your heart button